Replace Shell Navigation with FlyoutPage
I have an app using Shell flyout and tab navigation. Shell navigation has the disadvantage that page instances are re-used when visited more than once.  This doesn't happen with FlyoutPage, so is there a way to replace Shell navigation to achieve the same menu structure?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="LibraryAppM.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LibraryAppM.Views"
    Title="LibraryAppM"
    TitleColor="DarkCyan">
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <Tab Title="Information" Icon="lib_pic.jpg" Route="information">
            <ShellContent
                Title="Home"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
                Icon="home.png"
                Route="home" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Favourite"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FavouritePage}"
                Icon="favourite.jpeg"
                Route="favourite" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Recommended"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:RecommendedPage}"
                Icon="lib_pic.jpg"
                Route="recommended" />
            <ShellContent
                Title="Loans"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoansPage}"
                Icon="lib_pic.jpg"
                Route="loans" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <ShellContent
        Title="Enquiry"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:EnquiryPage}"
        Icon="enquiry.png"
        Route="enquiry" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Search"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SearchPage}"
        Icon="search.png"
        Route="search" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Update"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:UpdatePage}"
        Icon="update.png"
        Route="update" />
</Shell>


Shell navigation has the disadvantage that page instances are re-used when visited more than once.  Can you elaborate on what features you want specifically?

I should have read the docs more carefully.  I can change to FlyoutPage for the main menu and include a TabbedPage for the tabs.  Just working on completing this now.  (I must remember to RTFM).
